# Define partial specialization of Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of classes that all vary only by a string and a function, like so:

```
class ClassOne:
    __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
        self._my_str = 'hello'

    def greet():
       fun1(self._x)
       return self._my_str

class ClassTwo:
     __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
        self._my_str = 'howdy'

     def greet():
         fun2(self._x)
         return self._my_str
```

I would love to be able to define

```
ClassOne = ClassTemplate('hello', fun1)
ClassTwo = ClassTemplate('howdy', fun2)
```

So that ClassOne and ClassTwo still act as normal classes, i.e. can be imported into other modules and the likes. I realise this is probably a standard technique, but not knowing its name I cannot manage to Google it (that also explains my inability to properly name the question)

I realise I can take them in as part of the init, but the choice of function and string is not obvious for the user at all, so I would prefer to name them.

Edit: It seems people misunderstand what I seek. Continuing the example I want to be able to do

```
first_instance = ClassOne(3.14)
second_instance = ClassTwo(2.71)
first_instance.greet()
```

I.e. ClassOne and ClassTwo need to be proper class definitions.

Comment: Should `_my_str` really be a read-only class attribute, rather than an instance attribute?

Comment: It would be better if it were not an attribute at all, but it will be different between the classes and would be inappropriate to pass in the initialisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_my_str` can be *class* attribute, which you can set using
`__init_subclass__` provided by an appropriate base class. We'll make `fun` a static method so that the user doesn't have to define `fun` specially.

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, my_str=None, fun=None):
        cls._my_str = my_str
        cls._fun = staticmethod(fun)

    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def greet(self):
        self._fun(self._x)
        return self._my_str


class ClassOne(BaseClass, my_str='hello', fun=fun1):
    pass

class ClassTwo(BaseClass, my_str='howdy', fun=fun2):
    pass
```

(If you just used `cls._fun = fun`, then `self._fun(self._x)` would be equivalent to `type(self)._fun(self, self._x)`, rather than the intended `type(self)._fun(self._x)`.)

Alternately, you can simply declare the class attributes explicitly, though now the caller is responsible for correctly defining `fun` as a static method.

```
class BaseClass:    
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def greet(self):
        self._fun(self._x)
        return self._my_str


class ClassOne(BaseClass):
    _my_str = 'hello'
    fun = staticmethod(fun1)


class ClassTwo(BaseClass):
    my_str = 'howdy'
    fun = staticmethod(fun2)
```

In either case, you can defer setting the class attributes:

```
class ClassThree(BaseClass):
    pass

# time passes

ClassThree._my_str = "g'day"
ClassThree.fun = staticmethod(fun3)
```

Comment: That is beautiful! I started looking into metaprogramming based on an earlier comment now deleted, but this reads much more like normal code!

Comment: Why is it important to define fun as a static method in the alternative solution?

Comment: If you don't, it will be treated as an instance method, and `self.fun(...)` will try to pass `self` as the first argument to whatever function you used. An instance method is really just a `function`-valued class attribute.

Comment: `__init_subclass__` was added in Python 3.6 to handle cases that didn't require the full power of a metaclass. As a regular class method, it composes much more easily than metaclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the classes take in parameters when creating them

Update:
To name parameters, set a default value

```py
class ClassThing:
   def __init__(self, x, string=None, function=None):
      self.x = x #whatever x is
      self.string = string
      self.function = function

   def greet(self):
      self.function(self.x)
      return self.string
```

Then you can do

```py
>>> classthing1 = ClassThing(32, string = "hello1", function = lambda x: print(f"LOL {x}"))
>>> classthing2 = ClassThing(129, string = "hello2", function = lambda x: print(f"LOL lmao {x}"))
>>> classthing1.greet()
LOL hello1
32
>>> classthing2.greet()
LOL lmao hello2
129
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I wrote I wasn't willing to do? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Edited because I was way off
As you don't want to pass the function in the init you can do this

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
        self._my_str = 'hello'
        self.fun = None

    def greet(self):
       self.fun(self._x)
       return self._my_str

def fun(x):
    print(x)

def ClassTemplate(s, f):
    res = BaseClass(s)
    res.fun = f
    return resr

a = ClassTemplate('toto', fun)
a.greet()
```

Comment: I don't want to pass the function and string at initialisation. The user knows how to choose x, but not the string and function.

Comment: So what you're looking for is a class factory ?